# Count of barcodes by hour query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need help in my query the goal here is to get the count of barcodes by the hour so example here in the image you see the hour starting 16:46 to 16:58 so then the case count of barcode it should gives us a result of 24 caseCount by hour and so on, if another time starts at 15:01 to 15:59 then it should also count the barcode.

[image]

```
select      CodeSearch, 
            count(BarCode) as countCases,
            t_stamp    
from        dbo.stackerhistory    
group by    CodeSearch, t_stamp    
order by    CodeSearch, t_stamp
```

Comment: What is exactly is a problem? Do you know how to get just date and 24-hour components out of your `t_stamp`?

Comment: I need to be able to get the barcode count by hour no need to get the hour time from the t_stamp.

Comment: In order to aggregate (such as `count`)  by some parameter you need first of all to be able to get the value of such parameter for each row.

Comment: no need to add a parameter I just to be able to accomplish just with the query without a parameter. just as run the query and get the barcode count by hour

Comment: Please don't use images for data - use formatted text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is how you can do it :

```
select
    CodeSearch,
    DATEPART(HOUR,t_stamp) htime,
    count(BarCode) as countCases,
    t_stamp
from
    dbo.stackerhistory
group by
    CodeSearch,
    DATEPART(HOUR,t_stamp)
order by
    CodeSearch,
    DATEPART(HOUR,t_stamp)
```

this is per hour , however I assume you need to have per day/hour , so you can group by day as well:

```
select
    CodeSearch,
    DATEPART(HOUR,t_stamp) htime,
    CAST(t_stamp as Date) daydate,
    count(BarCode) as countCases,
    t_stamp
from
    dbo.stackerhistory
group by
    CodeSearch,
    DATEPART(HOUR,t_stamp),
    CAST(t_stamp as Date)
order by
    CodeSearch,
    CAST(t_stamp as Date),
    DATEPART(HOUR,t_stamp)
```

Comment: hello @eshirvana that worked perfectly, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the OVER window function with count. This query is similar to the one you have above, so it will give you 1-to-1 rows of the source. NOTE: this query does not differentiate DATES, so you might want to limit the DATE in a WHERE clause.

```
select CodeSearch
     , count(Barcode) over (partition by CodeSearch,datepart(hh,t_stamp)) as CaseCount
     , t_stamp
  from dbo.stackerhistory
```